# Does Trigger.io have an API to cache Media files for offline access?

Tags: html, cordova, media, offline-caching, trigger.io

I read thru the [caching documentation](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/features/cache.html) on Trigger.io Forge site. But I was unable to find out if they support caching media files for off-line access. Mobile Safari does not support caching media files for HTML5 apps.

Comment: This is totally doable using trigger.io.  Actually I am adding this feature to the next version of my trigger.io iOS and Android apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible with our [forge.file.cacheURL](http://current-docs.trigger.io/modules/file.html#cacheurl) method